# Divide and Conquer majority element algorithm

Tags: algorithms, arrays, correctness-proof, divide-and-conquer

The algorithm should return the majority element if it exists (majority meaning that there are $> n/2$ occurrences in the array)

I came up with this linear divide and conquer algorithm, but I'm not sure if it's correct. It returns an array with two elements, the name of the majority element and a number that is less than or equals to its occurrences. Can someone help to prove/disprove it?

```
def findMajority(arr):
    if len(arr) == 1:
        return [arr[0], 1]
    else:
        leftHalf = findMajority(arr[:len(arr)/2])
        rightHalf = findMajority(arr[len(arr)/2:])

        if leftHalf[0] is None and rightHalf[0] is not None: #Left half is indeterminate
            return [rightHalf[0], rightHalf[1]]

        if leftHalf[0] is not None and rightHalf[0] is None: #Right half is indeterminate
            return [leftHalf[0], leftHalf[1]]

        if leftHalf[0] is None and rightHalf[0] is None: #Both halves are indeterminate
            return [None, 0]

        if leftHalf[0] == rightHalf[0]: #Majority in both halves is the same
            return [leftHalf[0], leftHalf[1] + rightHalf[1]]

        elif leftHalf[1] < rightHalf[1]: #Right majority has more occurrences
            return [rightHalf[0], rightHalf[1]]

        elif leftHalf[1] > rightHalf[1]: #Left majority has more occurrences
            return [leftHalf[0], leftHalf[1]]

        else: #There is no winner between the two halves and they have equal occurrences
            return [None, 0]
```

EDIT: It returns the wrong answer for [2,2,2,2,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0]
. So it doesn't work.

Comment: @xavierm02 But in this case there is no majority, there needs to be more than $n/2$ occurrences

Comment: @xavierm02 There is still no majority, there needs to be an element with 5 or more occurrences

Comment: How about $[0;1;1;1]$?

Comment: @xavierm02 It works in this case.

Comment: If you're looking for a linear time algorithm, try this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_majority_vote_algorithm

Comment: @xavierm02 It works too. My intuition is if it works for [0,1,0,1,0,1...,0] then it should work for all test cases.

Comment: I depends on what you call working. It fails to return the correct number of occurrences and my feeling is this I should be able to use this in a bigger array to make it fail to find the correct element.

Comment: On $[0,1,1,0]$, it returns $[None, 1]$.

Comment: I finally managed to make it give a "really" wrong answer: $[0,1,1,1,  0,1,1,1,  0,1,1,1,  0,1,1,1,  2,2,2,2,  2,2,2,2,  2,2,2,3, 4,5,6,7]$ return $[2,10]$ even though $1$ appears $12$ times while $2$ only appears $11$ times. The idea is that $0,1,1,1$ makes it count $1$ only twice while it's there $3$ time and $1,1,1,1$ makes it count it $4$ times and it's really here $4$ times. So you just have to make the difference between the estimate and the real value big enough to have space for another number to have some number of occurrences in between.

Answer (score 2):

It's not correct. On input `[a a b c]`, the left side yields `[a, 2]`, the right side yields `[nil, 1]`. They would be merged into `[a, 2]`.

I'll outline a linear time solution. If there exists a value $x$ such that more than $n/2$ of the elements of $A$ have value $x$, then certainly the $n/2$-th order statistic of $A$ must be $x$. The selection problem is solved in linear time using, for example, median of medians; checking that such value does indeed appear at least $n/2$ times is trivially linear time.

Comment: But the only requirement is that it output the majority element if it exists. In this case 0 will need to appear more than 2 times so I don't think it is relevant for this case?